# Typesciprt Dynamic function arguments with GENERICS

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Hi I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YE_3WwX-Dl8 to create dynamic function arguments with generics in typescirpt. `sendEvent` function is now property typed as I wanted but I am finding hard time to get `args` type inside the function. First argument is properly typed but second argument type is always `unknown`. How can I get proper type of second argument based on first argument?

```
export type Event =
  | { type: "LOG_IN"; payload: { userId: string } }
  | { type: "SIGN_OUT" };


const sendEvent = <Type extends Event["type"]>(
  ...args: Extract<Event, { type: Type }> extends { payload: infer TPayload }
    ? [type: Type, payload: TPayload]
    : [type: Type]
) => {
  const eventType = args[0]; //  "LOG_IN" | "SIGN_OUT"
  const eventPayload = args[1]; // unknown. 
  // How to get proper type of second argument -> payload

};
```

Comment: I don't think anyone is going to watch a video to get context for this question.  Hopefully we don't need it.

Comment: What do you consider the "proper" type?  Personally I'd be inclined to refactor `sendEvent()` to look like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WK9aMN), where the event is a mapping from type to payload (so we don't have to play games with `Extract`), and the function is overloaded so that the implementation is freed from having to worry about exactly where the `undefined` it gets for the payload came from.  If that addresses your question fully then I can write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** Sadly, you cannot do that. To be completely honest, the example from the video may not be the best example to follow.

Let's break it down, why are you getting the `unknown`:

I will begin by creating an alias for the complicated type given to `...args`:

```
type TypeOfArgs<Type extends Event['type']> = Extract<Event, { type: Type }> extends { payload: infer Payload }
  ? [Type, Payload]
  : [Type]
```

All I did here is give the type a name `TypeOfArgs`. So far very simple. Now the difficult question - what is `Type`? `Type` is a subtype of `"LOG_IN" | "SIGN_OUT"` ... so `Type` could be one of the four following types `"LOG_IN" | "SIGN_OUT"`, `LOG_IN`, `SIGN_OUT` and `never`.

Let's see this in action:

```
const a: TypeOfArgs<'LOG_IN'|'SIGN_OUT'> = ['LOG_IN'] // Note `payload` is not defined, but my type-check says types are correct!
const b: TypeOfArgs<never> = [5 as never, 6 as unknown] // Note that I am assigning some complete rubbish here and type-check says types are correct!
const c: TypeOfArgs<'LOG_IN'> = ['LOG_IN', { userId: '123' }] // works as you want it
const d: TypeOfArgs<'SIGN_OUT'> = ['SIGN_OUT'] // works as you want it
```

I think by now you can see where the problem is. Only the last two examples (where `Type` is a **single** value) work as you wanted, the rest does not at all work as you wanted. And this is the root of your problem. (You / author of the video forgot about cases **a** and **b**).

In the video he shows how type checking works great on this example

```
sendEvent('LOG_IN', { userId: '123' })
sendEvent('SIGN_OUT')
```

which is all very nice and beautiful, but it only works because in this particular use case, the types are equivalent to this:

```
sendEvent<'LOG_IN'>('LOG_IN', { userId: '123' })
sendEvent<'SIGN_OUT'>('SIGN_OUT')
```

In other use cases - as you have correctly pointed out - the types simply fail - it is incorrectly typed.

...

**Is there an easy fix to this complicated type that would do what we want (cover only cases **c** and **d**, not **a** and **b**)?** - Not that I am aware of.

...

My advice: avoid complicated types like this. In your case, the code can be typed extra simply:

```
const sendEvent = (event: Event) => {
  if (event.type === 'LOG_IN') {
    // Note that here typescript already knows that payload must be present and have type { userId: string }
    console.log('event.payload: ', event.payload)
  }
}
sendEvent({ type: 'LOG_IN', payload: { userId: '123' }})
sendEvent({ type: 'SIGN_OUT' })
```